# When I run 'tensorflow-mnist-tutorial' and I got this: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead

Tags: python, tensorflow

when I running the Tensorflow's official sample code: '[tensorflow-mnist-tutorial](https://github.com/martin-gorner/tensorflow-mnist-tutorial)':

```
$python3 mnist_1.0_softmax.py
```

and something wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/holmes/Desktop/untitled/gitRepository/tensorflow-mnist-tutorial/mnist_1.0_softmax.py", line 78, in <module>
    I = tensorflowvisu.tf_format_mnist_images(X, Y, Y_)  # assembles 10x10 images by default
  File "/Users/holmes/Desktop/untitled/gitRepository/tensorflow-mnist-tutorial/tensorflowvisu.py", line 42, in tf_format_mnist_images
    everything_incorrect_first = tf.concat(0, [incorrectly_recognised_indices, correctly_recognised_indices]) # images reordered with indeces of unrecognised images first
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1047, in concat
    dtype=dtypes.int32).get_shape(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 651, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 716, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 176, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 165, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 367, in make_tensor_proto
    _AssertCompatible(values, dtype)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 302, in _AssertCompatible
    (dtype.name, repr(mismatch), type(mismatch).__name__))
TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.
```

Comment: Please post code here and also add full track back of error

Comment: I checked the git repository again. I found that this code version is not available for Tensorflow_1.0 and the author also said that they would make a update next week.